# GraphicsMagick - merge images

Tags: linux, image, png, graphicsmagick, command-line-interface

I want to create 120x240 transparent image and put some images on it with positioning. I found this:
`gm convert -background black \
    -page +0+0      a.jpg \
    -page +256+0    b.jpg \
    -page +0+256    c.jpg \
    -page +256+256  d.jpg \
    -minify \
    -mosaic output.jpg`

But I need to put it to fixed-sized transparent image. How can I do it?

Comment: If you want your output image to have the dimensions 120x240, then placing anything at coordinate values of 256 is going to place them outside the image, in which case, why bother?

Comment: That was what I found. I know that I have to rewrite it.